# MySQL: поиск по регулярному выражению

Tags: php, mysql

Есть большая таблица с названиями улиц. Мне необходима выбрать из нее только те, которые содержат дефис и названия, например "Тверская-Ямская 1-я".

Я составляю запрос:
      `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE street REGEXP '/^[А-Яа-я]+\-[А-Яа-я]+\s[0-9]+[-я]+/ui'`

Результатом должно быть примерно такая таблица:

```
+------+---------------------+
| id   | street              |
+------+---------------------+
| 5    | Тверская-Ямская 1-я |
| 6    | Тверская-Ямская 2-Я |
| 7    | Тверская-Ямская 3-Я |
| 4    | Тверская-Ямская 4-Я |
+------+---------------------+
```

Но в моем случае результат пуст.

Я попробовал проделать то же самое в php:

`preg_match('/^[А-Яа-я]+\-[А-Яа-я]+\s[0-9]+[-яЯ]+/ui', 'Тверская-Ямская 1-я', $matches);`

И я вижу результат:

```
Array
(
     [0] => Тверская-Ямская 1-я
)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

У вас не работает т к используются не допустимые символы для sql регулярных выражений, такие как "/ /ui","\s".
Вы могли бы обойтись и без регулярных выражений, напирмер оператором LIKE:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE street "%-% %-%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить условие отбора следующим образом:

```
WHERE street REGEXP '[а-я]+-[а-я]+ [0-9]+[-я]'
```

[Регулярные выражения в MySQL](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/mysql-man-4.0-ru/regexp.html)